# Implementing traffic signal in Android

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I'm trying to implement a traffic signal which will change color form red to green then to yellow. For this I used a button and I'm changing the background of the button to respected color. I'm using `CountDownTimer` for this purpose. Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button button1 = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        while(true){
            change(Color.GREEN);
            change(Color.BLUE);
            change(Color.RED);
        }
    }

    void change(final int color) 
    {
        CountDownTimer ctd = new CountDownTimer(3000, 3000) 
        {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long arg0) {}

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                button1.setBackgroundColor(color);
            }
        };
        ctd.start();
    }
}
```

But the above code doesn't seems to work, the color of the button is not at all changing. What's the problem in this code?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

    Button button1 = null;
    long timeout = Long.MAX_VALUE;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

        change();
    }

    void change() {
        final int[] colors = {Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.RED};
        CountDownTimer ctd = new CountDownTimer(timeout, 3000) {

            int current = 0;

            @Override
            public void onTick(long arg0) {
                Log.d("TEST", "Current color index: " + current);
                button1.setBackgroundColor(colors[current++]);
                if (current == 3)
                    current = 0;
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
            }
        };

        ctd.start();
    }
}
```